# Sitecore JSS integrated mode with subsites

Tags: webapi, jss

I have created separate bindings for the basic and advanced sample JSS apps as outlined in

```
https://jss.sitecore.net/#/setup/sitecore-config?id=sitecore-configuration
```

- 127.0.0.1    JssBasicApp
- 127.0.0.1    JssAdvancedApp

This works fine. When I click through the advanced app, I can see calls to the layoutservice like:

```
http://jssadvancedapp/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/portfolio&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey={KEY}
```

However, when I don't use separate IIS bindings, but instead configure subsites for JssBasicApp and JssAdvancedApp, the layoutservice calls get problematic. When I click through the advanced sample app, in the network tab in my browser I see calls like:

```
http://jss-sc.com/jssadvancedapp/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/jssadvancedapp/portfolio&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey={KEY}
```

resulting in a 404 not found error:

> http://jss-sc.com/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx?item=/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss&user=sitecore\admin&site=jssadvancedapp

Obviously, the Sitecore layoutservice is not called here, but Sitecore is trying to find the item `/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss` under the JssAdvanced node.

The following call gives a 404 error (removed the jssadvancedapp section after hostname):

```
http://jss-sc.com/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/jssadvancedapp/portfolio&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey={KEY}
```

Adding `&site=jssadvancedapp` to the url gives the same 404 error.

So the question is, what is the right api call? And how to set the configuration so that the right api call is made instead of the above wrong one.

This is how the sites configuration looks like:

```
<sites>
<site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" contentLanguage="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableTracking="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="15MB" viewStateCacheSize="1MB" xslCacheSize="25MB" disableBrowserCaching="true" enableItemLanguageFallback="false" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false" itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity" itemwebapi.access="ReadWrite" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" patch:source="Sitecore.Speak.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableTracking="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" language="en"/>
<site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx"/>
<site name="service" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service"/>
<site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
<site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true"/>
<site name="jssadvancedapp" inherits="website" virtualFolder="/jssadvancedapp" physicalFolder="/jssadvancedapp" rootPath="/sitecore/content/jssadvancedapp" startItem="/home" database="master" patch:source="jss-advanced-app.config"/>
<site name="jssbasicapp" inherits="website" virtualFolder="/jssbasicapp" physicalFolder="/jssbasicapp" rootPath="/sitecore/content/jssbasicapp" startItem="/home" database="master" patch:source="jss-basic-app.config"/>
<site name="website" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" enableItemLanguageFallback="false" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false" itemwebapi.mode="Off" itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" patch:source="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<site name="scheduler" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
<site name="system" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
<site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
<site name="exm" inherits="shell" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" startItem="/none" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" patch:source="Sitecore.EmailExperience.Core.config"/>
```

Comment: Great question. In order to sort it out, would you be able to paste in your sites configuration? The <sites /> section from /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Comment: Pasted in the <sites> configuration

Comment: Thanks! I don't think you are missing anything obvious here as I am seeing the same on my end. Need to debug it a bit. Gut feeling is that the site resolver based on virtualFolder and physicalFolder doesn't work well with SSC. Please stay tuned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try the following solution?

1. Add the following after line 10 in `advanced-sample-react\src\dataProvider\DataProvider.prod.js`: `params.sc_site = 'jssadvancedapp';`

   For context:

   `const getFetchOptions = (language, options = {}) => {
     const params = options.params || {};
     params.sc_site = 'jssadvancedapp';
     ...`

   > this forces the site context switch via query string. The value will vary per JSS app naturally.
2. Drop [this DLL](https://sitecore.box.com/s/me5m29n1t2djb20ed5zoolicc2d2wjg3) into the `/bin` (make a copy of your current `Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.dll` prior to that)

Please let us know if this fixes the issue so we can put the official fix out for the next update.

Comment: ok, I'll check it out and will let you know.

Comment: This works! I see now that in the api call the sc_site parameter is added: &sc_site=jssadvancedapp and the api now returns the expected json. Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for confirming the fix. This will be addressed in JSS Tech Preview Update-2.

Comment: This is now fixed in Preview 2. Adding “sc_site” Parag is still needed but the server now behaves properly ;-)